# Fix for bash line-wrapping & backspace display bugs on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, bash

When I open up Terminal (on Mac OS X 10.5.8) and type a long command line:
[image]

...the text doesn't go to the next line when it wraps around:
[image]
[image]

Also, sometimes when I type a command and then backspace (or up-arrow or ^U):
[image]

...the entire line isn't erased and I can't backspace beyond a certain point:
[image]
[image]

Is this a known bash bug (on Mac OS X)?  Is there a fix?

**Update:** [Juliano](https://serverfault.com/users/1276/juliano) was correct, the problem was caused by incorrectly delimiting a console code sequence in my PS1 variable.  Changing:

```
export PS1='\[\033[1;34m\]\$\]\033[0m\] '
```

...in my `.bashrc` to:

```
export PS1='\[\033[1;34m\]\$\[\033[0m\] '
```

...solved the problem.

Comment: +1 for the most beautiful screen shots of a terminal screen I have ever seen.

Comment: the two code lines you showed in your update are identical.

Comment: Good catch, @Magne. It's been four years since I looked at this, so I don't remember specifically, but I assume the "before" was missing a `\]`.

Comment: they are not identical: the 1st one has `\]` instead of '\[\`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The behavior is consistent to having console codes in your prompt (to change the color, etc.) and not properly marking then so that bash knows that they are invisible.

Before anything else, do this:

```
PS1='\w\$ '
```

And then try again. If the problem is solved, then my suspicions are correct.

Each console code sequence must be delimited with `\[` and `\]` in the PS1 variable. They tell bash that whatever is in there doesn't move the cursor position. Read the bash manual for more information.

Comment: That was the problem.  Thank you!  I'll update my question with details.

Comment: And what if it doesn't solve the issue?

Answer (score 4):

To help generate a sanitized prompt try http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html it's pretty awesome. Just be careful with brackets in your prompt, it tries to escape them or something.

Comment: +1 While @Juliano's answer is technically correct, this link here is what sets the correct `tput` commands - which has fixed newline, `\` newline and other "history + backspacing" fixes that using other ANSI codes could not fix.

Comment: that tool is awesome! Thank you for sharing it.